# Updating mysql row on certain days between time

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I am trying to look into making a function so I can update and switch "happy hour" on in my database.

reason for this is so users get extra stuff during this time.

So for instance what I want is... Friday and Saturday between 18:00 and 21:00 for happy hour to be on any other day of the week or times on them to days it would need to be off. days and times are just examples to give indication of how I need it.

```
function happy_hour(){
global $conn;
$getDay = time("l");
$getHour = time("H:i");
if ($getDay == "Wednesday" && $getHour > "12:00")  {
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Game SET happy_hour = 'yes' WHERE id='1' LIMIT 1");
}   
}

happy_hour();
```

I am not sure if it can be done from php time function or if would need to have a time stored within the mysql to access and then get the day and time and if on any of 2 days between times set to on then off.

Comment: You could use MySQL Events... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html if your server support them and the event scheduler is enabled..

Comment: Why do you need to store this in a database? Just do the date check on the game page?

Comment: What I am wanting to use is like an xp system and for different activities on different pages when completed on a certain day between the hours of that day for instance they would get extra xp, I am not sure which would be the best way.

Comment: rather than having a flag in the DB (which you then have to have a timer to switch off later), just store the "happy hour" schedule in the DB and let the code work it out based on that (vs the current time) whenever it runs. That also means you can very easily vary the schedule if you need to (just change the schedule records - next time the code runs, it'll use the new schedule), and you could potentially have different schedules for different types of bonuses or whatever. Watch out for issues with timezones etc which may or may not be applicable to your scenario

Comment: @BoxyGILLETT So you want to give users double xp in the weekends? I see no reason to use a database to do this.

Comment: Ok so how would I do it? if don't need a database the would rather not. I am not sure how else I could do it. :(

Answer (score 0):

If the time in your server and the database server is the same where you live everything will be OK. If not you must set the time, and for setting the between days you can use preg_match like

```
$day = time("l");

$hour = time("Hi");

if(preg_match($day, '/Friday|Saturday/') && $hour >= 1800 && $hour <= 2100) { 
do stuff here
}
```

Comment: When set up server with host I picked Europe server time is 1hr behind than client side due to time of year. tried this and it did not work even when changed time to today and between them times.

Answer (score -1):

```
$day = gmdate('l');
$hour = gmdate('H:i');

if ($day == "Wednesday") {

if ($hour >= "14:26" && $hour  <= "18:27") {
$isextra = true;
}else{
$isextra = false;   
}
}
```

Times or just examples but got it working, just the case of on activities with xp checking true or false.

```
if(isset($_POST['getXP'])) {
if($isextra == "true") {
$xpgained = 50;
}else{
$xpgained = 20;
}

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Account_Character SET rank_xp=rank_xp + '$xpgained' WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
}
```

This is only the sample i made, wanted it to work before get real into it.

Thanks guys :)